# How can I delete vector from vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, subtraction

how can I delete vector from vector?
For example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I delete `b=[2,3,5]` from above vector to be

```
c=[1,4].
```

I have a vector that has 100 elements.

Comment: `a(2:4) = []` also does the trick for your example above.

Answer (score 6):

```
c = setdiff(a,b)
```

should do the trick.